# Clickable jQuery object that passes values based on dynamic JSON results.

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for the best way to build some HTML 'objects' based on an array of jQuery objects that I have created. I then need each one to be clickable, and pull the values from the one that was clicked.

A bit of background...I'm building the objects from ajax calls to a external API service. The user searches for a name, then I end up with an array of objects with three properties (Id, ImageUrl, and Name).

I'm wondering if there is a 'easy'/clean way to display the Name and Image of the object and make it clickable...then when the object is clicked, I want to pass that Id back to the controller, which will in turn display a details page for the selected object.

What I currently have is all the jQuery to build the object, and then a results section:

```
<div id="results"> </div>
```

Then in the jQuery I call a function that appends to the div tag:

```
var div = $("<div class='well clearfix'>");
div.append($("<h4>").html(item.name));
```

I think the main concern is how to build the div tag in such a way that I can easily retrieve the Id of the object once it is clicked and pass it back to the controller.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Take it a step at a time, and then ask when you can not get a step working.

Comment: try `data-` attributes, read with jquery `data()` method

Comment: thanks on the data() method too...I originally thought it was for retrieving for some reason and never saw it could be used to store data along with the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data() to hold the item id, and event delegation to handle the click event

```
var $div = $('<div />', {
    'class': 'well clearfix item'
}).data('id', item.id);
$('<h4 />', {
    'html': item.name
}).appendTo($div);
//more contents

$div.appendTo('#results');
```

to handle the click event (need to be done in dom ready handler)

```
$('#results').on('click', '.item', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log('id:', id)
})
```